# Pass arguments to functions in addEventListener

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    numberButton[i].addEventListener('click', addNumber(numberButton[i].innerText))
```

I want to use numberButton[i].innerText inside the addNumber function when numberButton is clicked, but due to the fact that I can't use () inside addEventListener, otherwise the function will be called before the button click, I can't execute my idea. New to JavaScript here so sorry if I've made an obvious mistake.

Comment: @Andy now the OP has a new problem.

Comment: No need to pass it `function addNumber (evt) { console.log(evt.currentTarget.textContent, this.textContent); }` and `numberButton[i].addEventListener('click', addNumber);`